# How can I limit used functions in uploaded PHP file?

Tags: php, security, upload

I'm trying to make a plugin system and the plugin contain PHP code.
I think if someone evil reach the area that upload this plugin he can upload evil code
so I want to limit the functions used in plugin file such as if there is [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) or `base64_encode` function the upload should fail.

I think this will be done by the regex, but I have no experiance with it.

So I want something like that

```
<?php

$file = 'plugin.php';

$content = file_get_contents($file);

if(file_is_secure($content)){
    upload($file);
}else{
    exit('evil');
}

?>
```

see this example

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents('example.php');
    preg_match_all("/(function )(\S*\(\S*\))/", $content, $matches);
    foreach($matches[2] as $match) {
        $function[] = "// " . trim($match) . "<br />\n";
    }
    natcasesort($function);
    $functionlist .= "/* Functions in this file */<br />\n";
    $functionlist .= "/**************************/<br />\n\n";
    $functionlist .= implode('', $function);
    echo $functionlist;
?>
```

i want one like this but for making a white list and not for use functions, but for the function it self " i mean `function();` not `function name(){}`

Comment: You are in for a world of hurt allowing users to upload `.php` files.

Comment: This is quite dangerous and you might need to do a lot of work to make this secure.  Maybe you could describe what sorts of things you want to allow your users to do and we could provide a different solution?

Comment: the plugin is limited, this mean i can limit the used functions as i want

Comment: I think this will not help. It's still possible to run anything and eval is not the worst think what can happen. The user can create file after the plugin is installed and this file will contain any script, if you will include that file, it's like eval(). If you have control over the plugins then try to sign them and the will be validated with the signed string. If you want to limit the used functions, disable them in php.ini. There is no way to secure the uploaded scripts.

Comment: i said eval as an example , i want to make just white list

Comment: How do you want to check something like this?
$a = 'printf';
$a('%0.2f', 444);
You have to disable them on PHP level (ini file) on with the runkit (if your hosting company supports that)

Comment: i said, these plugins , i will write it, its very basic have no these things

Comment: So then make authorization and authenticate if the user can upload it, it will be only you who can do that. Second security level will be to have an API and validate the uploaded file with the API, it can be MD5 of the file and if you will be uploading zip files, it has to contain meta file and validate that meta file too. If you will write the script, you don't have to validate the file, if anyone else can upload them (their own script) you will not be able to secure them if you will not check that the file is yours.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension for PHP. This allows you to remove or redefine PHP functions, and to execute PHP code within a sandbox environment.